# how to pass a variable value from one flutter page to another

Tags: flutter

suppose, I have a file body1.dart where I created a variable "hello" which was initially empty!

```
String hello = "";
```

Now, in the same file, I have created a loop which will set and update the value of hello after every iteration!

Now the thing is whenever the value of "hello" get changed, I want to display that inside a Text Field which is in a different file body2.dart. I want to retrieve the real-time value at that exact moment! (Not the final outcome at the end of the loop)

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide code snippet for this? So that we can best assist you.

Otherwise the best option would be to use a stream. You can have multiple dart classes subscribed to the same stream.

**Streams** provide an asynchronous sequence of data. Data sequences include user-generated events and data read from files. You can process a stream using either await for or listen() from the Stream API

[Checkout official documentation from dart.dev](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams)

Comment: Please ask your question as a comment (not like the following:`Can you provide code snippet for this? So that we can best assist you.`).